# ffmpeg PHP variables in exec doesen't work

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

```
echo exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -framerate 1/5 C:\xamppp\htdocs\gen\image1.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\xamppp\htdocs\gen\out.mp4 2>&1');
```

This Works, but with "" it doesn't work.

and with "" and a variable in it it doesn't work.

```
echo exec("C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -framerate 1/5 -i C:\xamppp\htdocs\gen\$image.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\xamppp\htdocs\gen\$outputname.mp4 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:
If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters

(http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

You need to escape the backslashes to \\

And then, what you are doing is highly vulnerable to code injection. Better read up on [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)